# PostgreSQL: how to insert rows from text file into database table?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, insert-into

How may one read & insert rows from a textfile containing many URLs in [x, y, z] form for example:

1 google com (separated by tabs)

into a database table (without having to copy every single line out manually)?

I'm new at programming!

Thank you for your time and help kind sirs and madams!

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Database {

    public static Connection connectToDatabase(String user, String port, String database) {
        System.out.println("-------- PostgreSQL " + "JDBC Connection Testing ------------");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? " + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:" + port + "/" + database, user,
                    "doesn't matter!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static ResultSet executeSelect(Connection connection, String query) {
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return rs;
    }

    public static void dropTable(Connection connection, String table) {
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            st.execute("DROP TABLE " + table);
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createTable(Connection connection, String tableDescription) {
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            st.execute("CREATE TABLE " + tableDescription);
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int insertIntoTableFromFile(Connection connection, String table, String file) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        int numRows = 0;
        try {
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            String sCurrentLine, brokenLine[], composedLine = "";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Insert each line to the DB
                brokenLine = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                composedLine = "INSERT INTO dotcom VALUES (";
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < brokenLine.length - 1; i++) {
                    composedLine += "'" + brokenLine[i] + "',";
                }
                composedLine += "'" + brokenLine[i] + "')";
                numRows = st.executeUpdate(composedLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return numRows;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your Username:");
        String user = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Port ID:");
        String port = input.next();
        String database = "test";

        Connection connection = connectToDatabase(user, port, database);

        Statement st = connection.createStatement();

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            return;
        }
        // Now we're ready to work on the DB

        // read TopURLs file
        try {
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TopURLs"));

            while (fileReader.readLine() != null) {

                st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dotcom;");
                st.execute("CREATE TABLE dotcom (rank integer PRIMARY KEY, domainName varchar(128), domainType varchar(128));");
                //st.execute("INSERT INTO dotcom VALUES (fileReader.nextLine(), fileReader.nextLine(), fileReader.nextLine());");
                //st.execute("COPY dotcom FROM 'TopURLs' WITH DELIMITER as 'delimiter'");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

        // connection is of type Connection (in JDBC)
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = connection.getMetaData();

        // check if table is there
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "table name", null);
        if (tables.next()) {
            System.out.println("Table exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Table does not exist");
        }

        // check if view is there?
        //"create view foo as select * from table;"
        //"select * from foo;"
        ResultSet views = dbm.getTables("catalog name", null, null, null);
        if (views.next()) {
            System.out.println("View exists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("View does not exist");
        }

        String query = "SELECT * FROM branch";
        ResultSet rs = executeSelect(connection, query);
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print("Column 1 returned ");
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rs.close();

        dropTable(connection, "dotcom");
        createTable(connection,
                "dotcom (id int primary key, name varchar(15), type varchar(15));");
        int rows = insertIntoTableFromFile(connection, "customer", "src/Table.txt");
        System.out.println(rows + " rows inserted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code?

Comment: @Atri the INSERT INTO dotcom VALUES part (in the main method) I'm struggling with

Comment: what do you have in your text file ? queries in each line or query parameter values ?

Comment: A list of TopURLs e.g. 1 google com (next line) 2 facebook com

Comment: Is there an error? You don't see the inserted row in the table? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't want to manually insert the data entries of 5000 URLs into the database table in (x, y, z) form. Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: e.g. by a while loop, a for loop and a reader/scanner/writer method?

Comment: guess you don't want to use psql `\copy` ?

Comment: yeah I want to use insert

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data in the loop. Also you should use `PrepareStatement` with `executeBatch()`.

Below is the relevant modified code. I have assumed that your URLs are separated by single space. You can change the delimiter in the `line.split()`.

```
Statement createStatement = null;
PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;
try {
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TopURLs"));
    String line = null;
    createStatement = connection.createStatement();
    createStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE dotcom (rank integer PRIMARY KEY, domainName varchar(128), domainType varchar(128))");

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);//commit whole batch at the end
    insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dotcom VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    while ( (line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = fileReader.readLine();
        String[] urls = line.split(" ");//space or any other delimiter that you're using
        insertStatement.setString(1, urls[0]);
        insertStatement.setString(2, urls[1]);
        insertStatement.setString(3, urls[2]);

        insertStatement.addBatch();
    }
    insertStatement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(connection != null) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
    if(createStatement != null) {
        createStatement.close();
    }
    if(insertStatement != null) {
        insertStatement.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a nullpointer exception at st.execute("CREATE TABLE dotcom (rank integer PRIMARY KEY, domainName varchar(128), domainType varchar(128));");

Comment: 1. need to drop table: createStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dotcom");

Comment: 2. array out of bounds exception

Comment: The problem is that the data is in the form [int, String, String]. How may we use ints as well?

Comment: This line  `insertStatement.setString(1, urls[0]);` would become `insertStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(urls[0]));`

Comment: numberFormatException and parseIntException occured :(

Comment: how is this so hard? haha

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Get each line from file and store it as a String

  - So change `while (fileReader.readLine() != null)` to `while ((thisLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)`
- Since your data is tab delimited, you need to split it by tab and store as an array `String[]`

  - Do this: `String[] fields = thisLine.split("\t");`
- Now you can loop through this array and concatenate to create the insert query

  - Do this: `for (String s : fields) { //concatenate each field }`
- Execute the query

Comment: public static int insertIntoTableFromFile(Connection connection, String table, String file) {

  BufferedReader br = null;
  int numRows = 0;
  try {
   Statement st = connection.createStatement();
   String sCurrentLine, brokenLine[], composedLine = "";
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Insert each line to the DB
    brokenLine = sCurrentLine.split("\t");
    composedLine = "INSERT INTO dotcom VALUES (";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < brokenLine.length - 1; i++) {
     composedLine += "'" + brokenLine[i] + "',";

Comment: }
    composedLine += "'" + brokenLine[i] + "')";
    numRows = st.executeUpdate(composedLine);
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   try {
    if (br != null)
     br.close();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return numRows;
 }